# Informatica Powercenter Adding JOINs In SQL Override, mapping error

Tags: informatica

I have 5 views and I got them working in smaller Mapping projects, but I need to merge all the SELECT JOINs together. In my mapping I have

VIEWs -> SQ -> Exp Trans -> Aggregator -> Target File

In my first Mapping, I got the first 4 Views working together, but the 5th View (one to many and needs the Aggregator to Group) join is causing a mapping issue.

I added the 5th VIEW JOIN in the SQL Override section of SQ and mapped finally to the target. It executed but when I opened the csv, the columns looks like there were mis-mapped. The 5th View contains Phone number displayed phone number data like phone_number and phone_type. The phone number was not displayed on the csv fie but the phone type was which is an error since it was not mapped. One of my other column disappeared.

I started a new mapping and added the joins one at a time. I added the parent PERSON view first and then the next two were the one to many ie skills and phone. That went okay. When I added the 4th VIEW join, the mapping error happened again.

Has anyone encounter this before? Is this the right way to added 5 Joins in the SQL Override? Is there a better way to get all of them to work together?

Thanks,

Answer (score 1):

Make sure, you have the SELECT columns in SQ override **in the same order** as the ports in the SQ. Also, include only those columns in the SELECT clause, which you have **dragged from SQ to Expression transformation**.